# Deny SSH for a particular user from external network

Tags: ssh

So I have a server on my local network running an OpenSSH server. The server is configured to allow SSH from external networks, which is intended. However, I want to create one specific user (localUser), who must not login from outside my LAN.

Currently I have a group called sshusers, which is the only group allowed to login via SSH.

According to the man pages, it should be possible to use "Allow/Deny"Users but I didn't find out how to do it. Here is what I tried:

First attempt:

```
AllowGroups sshusers
AllowUsers localUser@192.168.2.* # 2 is not a typo
# localUser not in group sshusers. Intention: AllowUsers should override
# previous configuration, allowing access for localUser, even if he is
# not member of sshusers
```

Second attempt:

```
AllowGroups sshusers
DenyUsers localUser@!192.168.2.*
# localUser is member of sshusers. Intention: Access is granted, but with
# the negotiation of the match-expression for the LAN, access should be
# denied for external login.
# Also tried "!localUser@192.168.2.*"
```

I should mention, that denying the user from LAN but granting access from outside works:

```
# localUser member of sshusers
AllowGroups sshusers
DenyUsers localUser@192.168.2.*
```

However, I want to invert this configuration.

Any help is appreciated, but I prefer not using PAM or iptables for this.

Comment: Have you looked at `Match` and the explanation of `PATTERNS` in the man page for `ssh_config` (yes, that's without `d`, it is referenced in `sshd_config`, though)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But there is only a subset of keywords allowed in a Match block, and I don't see how I can use these to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try following:

```
AllowGroups sshusers
DenyUsers localuser@!192.168.2.*,
```

Note the comma after asterisk. So the syntax using `!` to negate the sense of the hostname match should be:

```
DenyUsers localuser@!192.168.2.*,!10.8.0.*,
```

which means that localuser should not be able to connect if host is different from those in the list.

As noted in comments this does not work with version equal or above `OpenSSH_7.4p1`. So I tried following (tested with `openssh-7.5p1`) which perfectly works:

```
DenyUsers localuser@*,!10.8.0.*
```

Such way localuser is denied from everywhere except from 10.8.0.*

Comment: This does not work. Using this configuration, I can login with localUser only, while all other users are locked out.

Comment: @Stephan, answer edited, can you check if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled to get this working. All that was missing was the comma at the end!!!

Comment: ...turns out this does *not* work with `OpenSSH_7.4p1`. Using the exact same syntax yields: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 89: invalid DenyUsers pattern` :-/

Comment: @maulinglawns, I'll add something to answer

Comment: Thank you @taliezin Did you try your latest version with `OpenSSH_7.4p1`? If so, did it work on that specific version? Br

Comment: @maulinglawns, I tested it on `CentOS` with `openssh-7.4p1` and it worked.

Comment: @taliezin Awesome. I tested it too, and it works. Thanks for your effort. If I could, I would give you TWO upvotes for this!

Comment: @maulinglawns, np ;), I am glad it helped.

Comment: I think the syntax `DenyUsers localuser@*,!10.8.0.*` is both simple to understand ("deny all hosts, but allow 10.8.0.*") and works with most versions. Nice!