# how to restrict SSH for specific user from specific subnet

Tags: linux, openssh

Is there any option to restrict SSH from specific user from specific subnet
for example: root@192.168.0.10/24 needs to be disabled.

Comment: Why not use a whitelist?

Comment: You can restrict the user in sshd_config with DenyUsers, with ip in /etc/hosts.deny or ip with iptables

Comment: I have tried  `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m owner --uid-owner ceetest5 -s 116.10.0.0/16 -j DROP` but got error like `iptables: Invalid argument. `

Comment: @BlockchainOffice with sshd_config, I was not able to configure subnet like `192.168.0.10/24 `

Comment: @bhr iptables can't look inside your SSH connection to see which user tries to log in, that's a bit the point of it being encrypted. So, iptables can't be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deny SSH for a particular user from external network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202467/deny-ssh-for-a-particular-user-from-external-network)

Comment: @BlockchainOffice: if I configure with subnet I am seeing error like `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 22: invalid DenyUsers pattern: "ceetest5@192.168.0.10/24"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it's [in the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

```
AllowUsers
             This keyword can be followed by a list of user name
             patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is
             allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.
             Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not
             recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all users.
             If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST
             are separately checked, restricting logins to particular
             users from particular hosts.  HOST criteria may
             additionally contain addresses to match in CIDR
             address/masklen format.  The allow/deny users directives
             are processed in the following order: DenyUsers,
             AllowUsers.
```

....however I personally would not use this - it would be a PITA to maintain a changing list of users. IMHO a better approach would be to use a Match block along with user groups....

```
Match 192.168.0.10/24
   AllowGroups PrivateSubnetSshUsers
Match 0.0.0.0/0
   AllowGroups SshUsers
```

BTW allowing direct access to the root account via ssh is usually considered an anti-pattern. Openssh even has specific configuration options to prevent this.

(Other things you might consdier are `AllowGroups root / AllowGroups !root' or 'PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no' along with the match blocks).